# Solve comctl32.dll missing in windows WinSxS

Tags: winsxs

Installed Tencent PC manager on win10  unfortunately it removed a dll file from "`C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_659******__****7f4c\`" folder, the files are in tencent quarantine, listed as Trojans.

When I try restoration I get an error

> Please make sure the path of recovery exists and is writable

And I can't install any new software, suggesting that comctl32.dll is missing from said location.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

In your antivirus software, whitelist the folder "C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_659******__****7f4c\"

As a quick win, under the security tab of the above folder add 'Everyone' to the security permissions with full read and write access.

Copy the DLL back over, once completed remove the 'Everyone' from the folder security permissions.

Try installing another program to see if it worked